# How do I web scrape this dynamic page?

Tags: angularjs, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to web scrape movie reviews from Rotten Tomatoes. An example would be for the following [movie](https://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/notebook/reviews/?page=9&type=user).

If I’m correct, this is a dynamic webpage, since when I try to go to the next page of the reviews the URL does not change for the website and page doesn’t refresh. Also, subsequently, when I try to web scrape normally using scrappy I can only get the reviews for that first page.

I am a beginner to web scraping and Selenium as well. I have tried the following code, having followed an online tutorial ([Scraping a JS-Rendered Page](https://stanford.edu/~mgorkove/cgi-bin/rpython_tutorials/Scraping_a_Webpage_Rendered_by_Javascript_Using_Python.php)):

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="/Users/me/Downloads/chromedriver")

url = "https://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/notebook/reviews?type=user"

browser.get(url)

innerHTML = browser.execute_script("return document.body.innerHTML")

print(innerHTML)
```

I expected to see the reviews on the second page, but it still only displays the first page reviews. What should I do to be able to scrape beyond the first page for all the reviews?

Comment: You're possibly violating part 2 of the website terms of use: "You shall not make a derivative use of the Services (or any part thereof) for any purpose, nor shall you download or copy information of users, or otherwise engage in data mining or similar data gathering." Generally you need to use the browser to navigate to the next page by clicking on a given page element, and waiting for it to load

Comment: This is for purely educational purposes. I’m just trying to learn about the topic myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not familiar with python web scraping, I will recommend a book for you.

[Web Scraping with Python, 2nd Edition](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920078067.do)

And I think using `requests` instead of `selenium` is more lightweight and elegant.

The following code may help you

```
import time
import requests

headers = {
    'Referer': 'https://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/notebook/reviews?type=user',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.108 Safari/537.36',
    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
}

url = 'https://www.rottentomatoes.com/napi/movie/00d1dd5b-5a41-3248-9080-3ef553dd9015/reviews/user'

payload = {
    'direction': 'next',
    'endCursor': '',
    'startCursor': '',
}

sess = requests.Session()

while True:
    r = sess.get(url, headers=headers, params=payload)
    data = r.json()

    if not data['pageInfo']['hasNextPage']:
        break

    payload['endCursor'] = data['pageInfo']['endCursor']
    payload['startCursor'] = data['pageInfo']['startCursor']

    for x in data['reviews']:
        user = x['user']['displayName']
        review = x['review']
        print(user, review)

    time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why are you using selenium. if you inspect the elements when you click on next a json request is going which is fetching the details.

For the URL, you mentioned I clicked on next and can find next [url](https://www.rottentomatoes.com/napi/movie/00d1dd5b-5a41-3248-9080-3ef553dd9015/reviews/user?direction=next&endCursor=eyJyZWFsbV91c2VySWQiOiJSVF85Nzc5MzU4MzIiLCJlbXNJZCI6IjAwZDFkZDViLTVhNDEtMzI0OC05MDgwLTNlZjU1M2RkOTAxNSIsImVtc0lkX2hhc1Jldmlld0lzVmlzaWJsZSI6IjAwZDFkZDViLTVhNDEtMzI0OC05MDgwLTNlZjU1M2RkOTAxNV9UIiwiY3JlYXRlRGF0ZSI6IjIwMTktMDMtMjFUMDg6MDA6MjIifQ%3D%3D&startCursor=).

maybe you can find a pattern in the URL for getting next URL and can **scrape** the details.